# Set PFQueryTableViewCell imageView as a local image

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, parse-platform

[Developing for iOS using Swift]

I am pulling data from Parse and populating a PFQueryTableView with it, and based on one of the values of the PFObjects that I am using to populate the tableView, I would like to set the imageView of the cell to an image stored locally in my Xcode images.xcassets.

This is my code:

```
// Set cells for each row of table
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell? {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! PFTableViewCell!
    if cell == nil {
        cell = PFTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    }

    // Set image as read/unread

    if let readStatus = object!["readStatus"] as? String {

        if readStatus == "unread" {
            cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "unreadImage")
        } else if readStatus == "read" {
            cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "readImage")
        }

    }

    return cell

}
```

But it does not set the image...

If I change this line with a ! after imageView (like so): `cell.imageView!.image = UIImage(named: "readImage")`

I get the error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

So how can I set the cell's image based on a Parse value (but I want the image to be a local image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is wrong with your cell object. First of all, you don't need the `!` mark at the end. You should have it like this:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! PFTableViewCell
```

In Xcode 6.3 and Swift 1.2 your next line would not compile because you are checking for nil something that cannot be nil - you are force unwrapping the cell so it is no more an optional and you don't need to check for nil.

So remove the `if cell == nil` lines and see if your cell is set up correctly in IB (check if you've set the identifier).

Comment: So this seems to work all good except the image being set in the imageView is stretching weirdly....

Comment: You can try something like this: `cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit`